# Как на странице разместить несколько форм с reCAPTCHA?

Tags: php

Мне нужно разместить несколько разных форм с Google reCAPTCHA. Как для этих форм использовать один ключ reCAPTCHA. У одной формы работает, а с другими нет. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: для начала было бы не плохо увидеть как вы это делаете (код)